# Kan extensions for linear categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let $C$ be a cocomplete category. Suppose that $X : A \to B$ is a functor, where $A$ is small. Then every functor $F : A \to C$ admits a left [Kan extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_extension) $\mathrm{Lan}_X(F) : B \to C$, defined by mapping $b \in B$ to $\mathrm{colim}_{X(a) \to b} F(a)$. The action on morphisms is as follows: If $\iota_{\sigma} : F(a) \to \mathrm{Lan}_X(F)(b)$ denotes the colimit inclusion induced by $\sigma : X(a) \to b$, then for a morphism $f : b \to b'$ we have $\mathrm{Lan}_X(F)(f) \circ \iota_{\sigma} = \iota_{f \sigma}$. This is well-known and easy to check.

Now I would like to work with $k$-linear (i.e. $\mathsf{Mod(k)}$-enriched) categories instead. So assume that $A,B,C$ are $k$-linear categories and likewise $X,F$ are $k$-linear functors. Then it doesn't seem to be the case that $\mathrm{Lan}_X(F)$, as defined above, is a $k$-linear functor again, right? So how can we explicitly construct a *$k$-linear* functor $\mathrm{Lan}_X(F)$ which serves as a linear left Kan extension (which I would define by a natural isomorphism of $k$-modules $\hom(\mathrm{Lan}_X(F),T) \cong \hom(F,T \circ X)$, where $T : B \to C$ is a $k$-linear functor)?

I'm aware that Kelly treats enriched Kan extensions in his book on enriched categories. But it doesn't seem to help me. I would like to know a down-to-earth construction without delving into general enriched category theory. After all, linear categories should be a very basic example.

Comment: There is a standard weighted colimit formula that always works (as explained by Kelly), and in some cases the weighted colimit can be reduced to an ordinary colimit.

Comment: Yes I kind of know that (without understanding it). I would like to see a "formula" for $\mathrm{Lan}_X(F)$ with which I can work.

Comment: I could try to explain that, but are you looking for something else?

Comment: Okay the formula http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end#kan_extension_40 means that for $k$-linear categories we should define $\mathrm{Lan}_X(F) := \int^{a \in A} \hom(X(a),-) \otimes_k F(a)$, right? Does this coend have the usual description, or does the enrichment play a role here?

Comment: If $A$ is an ordinary category and the target category is cocomplete in the ordinary sense and also tensored and cotensored, then (IIRC) the coend can be computed in the ordinary way. If $A$ is also enriched then it has to be an enriched coend.

Comment: In my case everything is linear, including $A$ and $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a Bénabou cosmos (complete and cocomplete symmetric monoidal closed category), let $\mathcal{A}$ be a small $\mathcal{V}$-category, let $\mathcal{B}$ be any $\mathcal{V}$-category, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a $\mathcal{V}$-category that is cocomplete in the ordinary sense as well as tensored and cotensored. Let $X : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ and $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{C}$ be $\mathcal{V}$-functors. A **pointwise left Kan extension** (which Kelly refers to simply as ‘left Kan extension’) is a left Kan extension that is preserved by representable functors, in the sense that
$$\mathcal{C} (\operatorname{Lan}_X F, C) \cong \operatorname{Ran}_X \mathcal{C} (F, C)$$
and the right hand side can be described by the following end in $\mathcal{V}$:
$$\operatorname{Ran}_X \mathcal{C} (F, C) \cong \int_{A : \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{V} (\mathcal{B} (X A, -), \mathcal{C}(F A, C))$$
Note that the right hand side, evaluated at $B$ in $\mathcal{B}$, is the *definition* of the hom-object
$$[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{V}](\mathcal{B}(X, B), \mathcal{C}(F, C))$$
and thus we obtain the following formulae in $\mathcal{C}$:
$$(\operatorname{Lan}_X F) B \cong \mathcal{B}(X, B) \star_{\mathcal{A}} F \cong \int^{A : \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{B}(X A, B) \otimes F A$$

Our problem is now to describe $\mathcal{V}$-enriched ends/coends. Let $H : \mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op} \otimes \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{C}$ be a $\mathcal{V}$-functor. Then, for $A$ and $A'$ in $\mathcal{A}$, we obtain a pair of morphisms in $\mathcal{V}$,
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A} (A', A) \otimes H (A, A') & \to H (A, A) \\
f \otimes z & \mapsto H (A, f) (z) \\
\mathcal{A} (A', A) \otimes H (A, A') & \to H (A', A') \\
f \otimes z & \mapsto H (f, A') (z)
\end{align*}
and the coend of $H$ is computed by the following coequaliser diagram:
$$\coprod_{(A, A') \in \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{A} (A', A) \otimes H (A, A') \rightrightarrows \coprod_{A \in \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{A}} H (A, A) \to \int^{A : \mathcal{A}} H (A, A)$$
Note that because $\mathcal{C}$ is cotensored, ordinary colimits and conical colimits coincide.

---

The question of whether enriched left Kan extensions can be computed using only (possibly iterated) colimits over ordinary diagrams essentially boils down to whether every $\mathcal{V}$-presheaf $\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{V}$ can be expressed as a (possibly iterated) colimit over an ordinary diagram of representable $\mathcal{V}$-presheaves. According to Kelly (§3.9), this is the case when $\mathcal{V}$ is $R\text{-}\mathbf{Mod}$, but I don't see why immediately.